# How to change an existing variable in a django template

Tags: python, django

Newish to Django here and need some assistance. I have a bool variable empty=True. I passed the variable through views to my template successfully. In the template I have a while loop that includes an if/else statement. I need to be able to change my variable to False if it meets a condition in the if statement. Once I'm out of the loop there is another if/else statement to check in empty is True.

I can't seem to figure out how to change a variable in the template.

I did try a with statement to change the variable but it didn't work correctly for me because I have to end the with statement before the loop ends. Once the with statement ends, the variable reverts back to its' original value

Views -
'''

```
def myProjects(request):
    user = request.user
    projects = Project.objects.all() #from db
    empty=True
    return render(request,'users/myProjects.html',locals())
```

'''
Template - 
'''

```
<div class="row" id="main1">
  <div class="col-2"></div>
  <div class="col-9">
    <div>
      <h1>My Projects: </h1>
      {% for x in proj %}
        {% if x.creator.user == me %}
          <div class="media1">
            <img class="account-img" src="{{x.projectPicture.url}}">
            <div>
              <h5><strong>Project Name: {{x.projectName}}</strong></h5>
              <p>Project Type: {{x.projectType}}</p>
              <p>Creator: <a href="/allUsers?name1={{x.creator.user}}"> {{x.creator.user}} </a></p>
              <p class="text-muted small">Created: {{x.dateTime}}</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          {{empty=False}}
        {% else %}
          {{pass}}
        {% endif %}

      {% if empty==True %}
        <p>You do not have any projects</p>
      {% else %}
        {{pass}}
      {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

{% endblock%}
```

'''

Comment: What have you tried?  Some code would make the question clearer and more likely to be answered.

Comment: Please include some code, for me it seems that the easiest approach would be to redesign, what we might help you with.

Comment: Even if you can find a way to set the variable, this is bad design. Why don't you simply pass the relevant project(s) to the template? This way you wouldn't have to iterate all projects to see if they belong to the user. You should implement most of the logic in your views and do simple layout formatting in your templates.

Comment: Still trying to get used to Django, now I understand.

Answer (score 0):

Setting variable values in templates is against Django's design philosophy. The template system is designed to [separate logic from presentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/misc/design-philosophies/#separate-logic-from-presentation) and [avoid being a programming language](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/misc/design-philosophies/#don-t-invent-a-programming-language).

To achieve what you are trying to do, you could first filter the projects in the view, then use the [for...empty](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#for-empty) tag. Your example would become something like the following:

```
{% for project in projects_created_by_me %}
  <p>Project Name: {{project.projectName}}</p>
{% empty %}
  <p>You do not have any projects</p>
{% endfor %}
```